# Is there any utility tools or scripting techniques for different vendor prefixes

Tags: jquery, css, utility, vendor-prefix

Basically I would prefer to choose standard css rule for different styles which contain different vendor prefixes. For testing purpose I would choose like this:

```
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #fff;
transform: rotate(90deg);
```

Later on, for finalizing, I would consider to have prefixes like this:

```
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #fff;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #fff;
trasform: rotate(90deg);
-moz-trasform: rotate(90deg);
-moz-trasform: rotate(90deg);
```

There are a lot of css prefixer but actually what I want is to modify all of my stylesheet. If there is not like my thoughts could we make it possible with jQuery?

Comment: CSS preprocessors (like Sass with [Compass](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/exclude_vendor_prefixes/)) take care of that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Sublime Text 2 has a plugin called Prefixr.  You just use the standard CSS property like what you want to do. When done it will hit up a web service to see what the current "safe" vendor prefixes are and apply them like you want.  If you highlight a single property it will only look that up otherwise it will scan the whole stylesheet.